# What's the point of viewing other user's profile?

Tags: discussion, profile-page

I want to know:

1. What are the reasons for viewing other user's profile?
2. Which benefits will we get?
3. In mostly , which conditions will lead to view other user's profile?
4. What is the most interesting point on other user's profile?

Any suggestions would be really appreciated.

Comment: `In mostly , which conditions will lead to view other user's profile?` -- Curiosity?

Comment: It just only discussion and I am still a newbie in SO and Meta.So , I want to get your opinions.

Comment: Opinion based questions are not "on-topic" on any Stack Exchange site.

Comment: @hims056 , thanks for teaching me.If so, what is the meaning of discussion tag. Awww...I need to tell I want to get reason.

Comment: @hims056, Thanks for meaningful editing. Sorry for my English.

Comment: If opinions can be based on facts (blog posts by devs, other questions, statistics, or simply the way things really are done here), it's OK discussion. Only opinions based on opinions are really bad. (Note, I'm talking about meta only)

Comment: @ Mołot, ahh... awsome knowledge. great.

Comment: @hims056 I definitely feel you and agree with that, but with a tiny caveat; We often express opinions related to feature requests and such on Meta sites.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

> What are the reasons for viewing other user's profile?

Because we want to know details about other users.

> Which benefits will we get ?

We get to know more about the user we want to know more about.

> In mostly , which conditions will lead to view other user's profile?

Human nature: we want something so we follow our desires. Seriously though, when I see a good post I want to see more from that user.

> What is the most interesting point on other user's profile?

Now that's totally opinion based... personally I find all details equal in "interest level", maybe badges bit more as they stand out.

Comment: I asked this question due to I always view the user profile who answer my questions and read their answers or questions ( these my tagged ) and study. My interesting point on them are their reputation,badges ( which Q or A these they get). So , I want to know another important things to check that I shouldn't miss.

Answer (score 11):

For me it mostly helps in moderation activities I can perform as a regular user. If I notice a particular user destroying own content, or performing a particularly bad review, or leaving terrible comments, it's often nice to be able to look into their history.

This allows me to judge if this is a persistent problem (which might require moderator attention) or if it's just a fluke/mishap that can be trivially dealt with by me and my particular privileges.

That's about as much practical use I get out of another user's profile and participation information.

Comment: I asked this question due to I always view the user profile who answer my questions and read their answers or questions ( these my tagged ) and study. My interesting point on them are their reputation,badges ( which Q or A these they get). So , I want to know another important things to check that I shouldn't miss.

Comment: @Cataclysm That really depends on what you're interested in. It's a purely personal thing. I don't really go through a user's profile all that much beyond some moderation related tasks.

Comment: Oh ! do you mean my question doesn't has exact answer ? I want to get some suggestions from experience users for me when I viewing profiles.

Comment: Well, I told you what I do with it. That's as much as I can tell you.

Comment: Please don't me mind. I really appreciated your answer. And my comment is not only for you. Thanks for your valuable times.